# Volume of a Cylinder With a Cylinder Cutout

Tags: geometry, volume

I was considering a cylinder with a cylinder cut out through the middle of it (on the curved side, parallel to the base) inspired by a doughnut themed coffee mug I saw. Would there be any way to obtain a general formula for the volume of such a cylinder? The volume of the overall cylinder is simple of course ($\pi r^2h$), and most of the cutout can be calculated easily enough. However, the ends where the cutout meet the edge of the cylinder are giving me trouble. The only way I can think of to solve it is using a triple integral, and that seems very messy. Would there be any better way to do this? Here are some pictures to show the situation for added clarity.

[The Entire Cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZcKR.jpg)

[The Simple Part of the Cutout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7r3T.jpg)

[The Complicated Part of the Cutout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z5TN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's calculate the entire small radius cylinder. Easy for me to set it up that way. Let's call $x$ the horizontal direction perpendicular to both cylindrical axes, $y$ the vertical direction (along the axis of the big cylinder), and $z$ the direction along the axis of the small cylinder. Also, call the radius of the small cylinder $r$, and of the big cylinder $R$. Not divide the volume of the small cylinder into rectangles perpendicular to the $x$ axis. You can see that the width in the $y$ direction is $2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, and the height in the $z$ direction is $2\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$. The limits of integration are from $-r$ to $r$:
$$V=8\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\sqrt{R^2-x^2}dx$$
Make the substitution $x=r\sin\theta$, $dx=r\cos\theta d\theta$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to work. The only problem is that the integral can't be evaluated exactly (at least not with any methods I know) since it involves both r^2-x^2 and R^2-x^2 in the square roots, but it does still seem to be the correct answer.

Comment: Some integrals don't have a nice analytical form. https://xkcd.com/2117/

Comment: Right. I was hoping for a nice analytical form, but like I said, it is still the correct answer.